# Launch a file path/url with open with dialog

Tags: x11, gio

I am trying to supply a path, and open it with the "native open with" dialog of linux.

This is the native open with dialog seen on ubuntu:

[image]

I looked into `GioLaunch` and am able to launch things into their default application handler, but i cant manage to launch it into this "Open With" dialog.

This is my code for launching into default app:

```
var launcher = g_desktop_app_info_new_from_filename('blah blah blah');

var error = new TYPES.GError.ptr();
var rez_launch_uris = g_app_info_launch_uris(launcher.address(), null, null, error.address())
```